# Typescript- initialise property of type that is user defined(class)

Tags: typescript

How to initialise a property in a class- preferred in the constructor. The property is of type class or enum that is defined by the developer.
Please if you can give me a working group sample, thanks.

Comment: anyone? an example of initialising a property of complex type - developer defined class

Answer (score 0):

> an example of initialising a property of complex type - developer defined class

What you are effectively asking for is a Dependency Injection Container. Writing one is not trivial.

A quick google search has shown this : https://github.com/maxgherman/TypeIOC and it looks promising.

Note that TypeScript *just recently* got *decorator* support and that would be the way to go for future DI work. Currently Angular 2.0 uses that code is not packaged for public consumption yet.